# modulus with remainder laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I am trying to setup columns of 4 from a laravel array which works correctly. The problem is how do you handle remainders? With my loop I end up with 2 extra divs that are empty at the end of my output. I have 10 items that i'm looping over which would give me a remainder of 2.5 Here is my code.

```php
<div class="serviceListingColumn">
     <ul>
         @foreach($serviceListings as $serviceListing)
           @if ($serviceListing->service_category == $services->title)
               <li class="serviceListingItem">{{$serviceListing->service_name}}</li>
           @endif
           @if($loop->iteration % 4 === 0)
               </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="serviceListingColumn">
                   <ul>
           @endif
        @endforeach
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest chunking the original array into groups, then just looping those. Easier for the template logic.

```php
// Use the Collection's group() functionality in your controller.
// Use collect() if it isn't a Collection already.

$array = collect($array)->chunk(4);

// Your template then doesn't need to worry about modulus,
// and can focus on displaying the chunked groups.

@foreach ($array as $group)
    <div class="serviceListingColumn">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($group as $serviceListing)
                <li class="serviceListingItem">{{ $serviceListing->service_name }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Big +1 for chunking. Great approach for this.